# Событие клавиатуры

Tags: android, kotlin

Я новичок в котлине и немного не понимаю, как словить событие, когда прользователь вводит в что-то EditText поле? Например, как сделать, чтобы, когда пользователь вводит что-либо и оно дублирует его в TextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю это вам поможет:

```
class MainActivity:AppCompatActivity() {

overridefunonCreate(savedInstanceState:
Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    editTextSample.addTextChangedListener(object:TextWatcher{

        overridefunafterTextChanged(s:Editable) {}

        overridefunbeforeTextChanged(s:CharSequence, start:Int,count:Int, after:Int) {}

overridefunonTextChanged(s:CharSequence,start:Int,before:Int, count:Int){
tvSample.setText("Text in EditText : "+s)
        
}
    
})

}
}
```

Comment: а для поля с типом time или number работает?

Comment: Должен работать. Не важно какой тип поля вы используете, всё равно вы можете получить строку

Answer (score 1):

Есть слушатель изменений текста `addTextChangedListener`:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
 
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {
    }
 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
      textView.setText(s);
    }
});
```

[вот туториал](https://metanit.com/java/android/4.8.php) по вашему вопросу.

### UPDATE_KOTLIN

```
val editText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editText)
editText.addTextChangedListener(object :TextWatcher{
   override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                
   }

   override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                
   }

   override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    val textView = findViewById<View>(R.id.textView) as TextView
    textView.text = s
   }

})
```

Comment: а для поля с типом time или number работает?

Comment: будет, единственно в ответе java, а не kotlin. что немного не по теме вопроса

Comment: @tosh17, студия мне кажется такие дела прожевывает нормально)

Comment: Если целиком вставить, то да, а если кусками копировать, то могут быть проблемы. Или если студия не поймет тип переменной то она вообще не преобразует. Новичок потом не разберется

Comment: @tosh17, спасибо что указали на эту неточность, обновил ответ :)

Comment: А за что отвечает s в этом фрагменте? у меня ошибку дает "textView.text = s"

Comment: спасибо, получилось, там вместо s надо написать p0)

Answer (score 1):

По скольку вы используете kotlin, то рекомендую использовать ktx
Для начала добавте зависимости в gradle

```
android {
      ...
    compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
}
}
dependencies {
... 
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
}
```

После чего в коде можете использовать более простые конструкии

```
editText.doOnTextChanged  { text, start, count, after -> 
       
    }
```

Comment: а для поля с типом time или number работает?

Comment: для слушателя это не важно, вам в любом случае возвращается CharSequence.

Comment: Странно, но почему у меня так получается?
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiWpvJjL5oj-hW9Ln6Q3d8OT1hDM?e=sGxwcG

Comment: вы создали переменную типа строка и пытаетесь у нее поставить слушатель. Применяйте на переменной типа EditText

Comment: спасибо, ваш вариант тоже помог)

Comment: они все правильные. Просто этот наиболее читаемый, так как меньше кода